# Remove Mac OSX Lion pre-installation of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

I'm running Lion 10.7.5, and I'm trying to install Postgresql 9.2.4 for use with Django. I have hit countless roadblocks and errors, so I would like to start with a totally clean slate.

I did a `brew uninstall postgresql` and removed any lingering folders from my attempted 9.2.4 installation. Now, I would like to completely remove the Mac installation `psql -V` 9.0.10.

What is the best method for doing this? or, is this definitely not recommended?

Note: I do not have a postgresql uninstaller app, so I'm interested in which files I need to manually delete (unless there's a better way of course.)

Comment: I'm not sure it's safe to do that. Personally I'd just leave it shut down and set my `PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to make sure the more modern version I installed myself was found first.

Comment: I'll go with your recommendation for now, considering it's the only response thus far. Thanks for your input.